# Unable to recreate Azure Maps (Not Found)

Tags: azure, azure-maps

Have attempted the following using ARM Templates, through the Azure portal and via the latest Azure Powershell scripts.

1. Create new Azure Maps account
2. Delete Azure Maps account
3. Create new Azure Maps account with same name from step 1

**Expected**: Azure Maps account is created and able to be used

**Actual**: Azure Maps is 'created' but attempting to retrieve or interact with the resource results in a 404 Not Found error. All blades in Azure just show

[image]

Is anyone aware if this is an existing limitation of Azure Maps or if there is a known workaround without having to create the maps account on a different name?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting. There is an issue with this process which started occurring late last night. The team is working on resolving this.

**Update (3/8/2019)**: This issue has now been fixed in production.